# Preview of face camera using surface view android

Tags: android, camera

I have the following java code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import com.testing.CameraOperations;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SurfaceView surface;
    private CameraOperations camera;
    private SoundOperations sound;
    private static boolean woken = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void test(View v){
        if(!woken){

            surface = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.cameraView);

            SurfaceHolder holder = surface.getHolder();
            surface.setCamera(camera.toggleFaceCamera());

            Animation out = AnimationUtils.makeOutAnimation(this, true);
            v.startAnimation(out);
            v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            woken = true;
        }
    }

}
```

And another class **cameraOperations**:

```
import android.hardware.Camera;

public class CameraOperations{

private Camera cam = null;
private Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
private static int camNumber = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

public Camera toggleFaceCamera(){

    if(cam == null){
        for(int counter = 0; counter < camNumber; counter++){
            Camera.getCameraInfo(counter, cameraInfo);
            if(cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT){
                try{
                    cam = Camera.open(counter);
                    return cam;
                }catch(RuntimeException e){return null;}
            }
        }
    }

    return null;

}

}
```

The function "test" is ran by button onclick and the animation works just fine. **I've read a bunch of tutorials and references to this BUT I haven't been able to successfully preview the camera to the user.** If someone could actually make me understand clearly and by coding the relation between the surface, the holder and the camera preview I would be much thankful!

Comment: Your code will not even compile. In [my book](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html), `SurfaceView` class does not have `setCamera()` method. To start preview, you call `Camera.setPreviewDisplay()` and then, `startPreview()`. See [example](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html)

Comment: @AlexCohn setCamera is deprecated, I had it commented in my IDE. I **explicitly** asked for a coded example or nothing since I am not understanding the whole mechanism behind camera preview, but ty anyway...

Comment: You can take https://github.com/alexcohn/JBcamera as a working ccomplete example.